# Does Gnome Keyring support new-format OpenSSH private keys?

Tags: ssh, openssh, ssh-agent, gnome-keyring, ssh-keygen

Does `gnome-keyring` support SSH private keys that are saved in the [newer OpenSSH file format](http://www.tedunangst.com/flak/post/new-openssh-key-format-and-bcrypt-pbkdf)?  Will Gnome Keyring automatically import those private keys?

In more detail: When generating a SSH private key, `ssh-keygen` can save the private key in the newer OpenSSH format (rather than the "more compatible PEM format").  With this format, the private key file begins with "`-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----`".

I just generated a new RSA private key for SSH and saved it in the newer format, using `ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 3072 -o -a 16`.  Now Gnome Keyring doesn't seem to be able to load that private key.  In contrast, everything seems to work fine when using `ssh-agent`.

When using Gnome Keyring with this new private key, I see the following error messages in `/var/log/messages`:

```
gnome-keyring-daemon[10904]: invalid or unrecognized private SSH key: [key id]
gnome-keyring-daemon[10904]: signing of the data failed: The operation failed
```

and when I try to run `ssh`, I see the following error message in my terminal:

```
sign_and_send_pubkey: signing failed: agent refused operation
```

If it's relevant, I'm using Fedora 25 with MATE, with `gnome-keyring-3.20.0-1.fc25.x86_64`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things have changed slightly now. As a result GNOME 3.28 now wraps OpenSSH's ssh-agent, which gives it the same level of support as OpenSSH.

*[Reference - Archlinux wiki - GNOME/Keyring](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GNOME/Keyring)*

> ### Known issues
>
> #### Cannot handle ECDSA and Ed25519 keys
>
> As of January 2018, GNOME Keyring doesn't handle [ECDSA](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=641082) nor
>   [Ed25519](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=723274) keys. You can turn to other [SSH agents](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SSH_keys#SSH_agents) if you need 
>   support for those.
>
> > **Note:** As of GNOME 3.28, gnome-keyring replaced its SSH 
> >     agent implementation with a wrapper around the ssh-agent tool 
> >     that comes with [openssh](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=775981). As a result, any type of key 
> >     supported by the upstream ssh-agent is now also supported by
> >     gnome-keyring, including ECDSA and Ed25519 keys.

If you still find that you're behind this particular version this Gist shows how you can use `keychain` to workaround this issue, titled: [SSH with ed25519 (curve25519) + GNOME-KeyRing](https://github.com/Zeitwaechter/SSH-with-ed25519-curve25519-GNOME-KeyRing).

#### References

- [new openssh key format and bcrypt pbkdf](https://www.tedunangst.com/flak/post/new-openssh-key-format-and-bcrypt-pbkdf)

Answer (score 3):

Alas, it appears that Gnome Keyring doesn't support the new-style file format for private keys, as far as I can tell.  At least, there are two bug reports on Gnome Keyring's bug tracker that make this claim:

- [Bug 750986](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=750986) says PBKDF2 isn't supported.  PBKDF2 is enabled by default for the new file format.
- [Bug 702529](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=702529#c1) says the new file format isn't supported (see comment 1).

Comment: The ed25519 is not supported either.